# Better way of extending React components

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have a none UI related plugin in vanilla javascript called SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy. Its a server - client pub/sub library.

I already have a Vue plugin and now look at implementing a React plugin. I need some lifetime knowledge of the component. One way is extending React.Component and let the users of the lib use this component instead of the orignal.

```
class MyEvent
{
   constructor(message) 
   {
       this.message = message;
   }
}

class SignalREventAggregatorComponent extends React.Component {
     subscribe(event, handler, constraint) {
         setTimeout(() => handler(new MyEvent("This comes from backend")), 1000); //signalR.eventAggregator.subscribe(event, handler, this, constraint)
     }

     publish(event) {
         //signalR.eventAggregator.publish(event);
     }

     componentWillUnmount() {
         //signalR.eventAggregator.unsubscribe(this);
     }
}

class TestComponent  extends SignalREventAggregatorComponent  {
  componentDidMount() { 
    this.subscribe(MyEvent, this.onEvent);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
     //Doing some teardown in TestComponent 
     super.componentWillUnmount(); // This is paramount to call
  }

  onEvent(e) {
     console.log(e);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is a bit fragile, first its not nice to force the users to extend a specific component like this. They might have another third party library they already extend etc. Second its fragile. The user needs to call `super.componentWillUnmount` otherwise my library will fail to unsubscribe the component and server side events will keep streaming in. (Plus it will be a memory leak). Is there a nicer way?

I need to know when the component dies, plus I must know its context (this keyword basically). Also the component need a nice way of calling methods on the plugin to subscribe and publish events.

Any ideas?

Comment: can't it be a react hook?

Comment: Did you consider creating `SignalREventAggregatorComponent` as an HOC? https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html
It may suit your need.. Though, the users will still need to use the HOC, so write something like `SignalREventAggregatorComponent(ComponentCreatedByUser)`, but you wouldn't have problem with extends nor the needing to call `super.componentWillUnmount`

Comment: If typescript is a possibility for you, see here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21388

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of inheritance, you can create a [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) and use it with your `TestComponent`!
Check out [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/8xxjlo93zj).

Comment: Thanks for a working example. Would you say HOC is more common for this than a custom hook?

Comment: Yes!
Though if you have several components, that should share the same handler, you may want to use a Provider.

Comment: Nah, that defeats the purpose of a event aggregator :P Thanks man, will test and accept

Comment: One final piece of the puzzel is missing. From the subscribe I need to get the context of the wrapped component. the this keyword does not point to same context

Comment: What context do you need? Can you edit my codesandbox and show me what you are planning to do?
Maybe you are using a normal function instead of an arrow function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189529/discussion-between-lorenz-henk-and-anders).

Answer (score 0):

You can use some kind of a provider that the user will wrap his root component with, similar to what react-router or redux are doing. And also provide a wrapper component that will do the subscription.

Here's an example:

Root component rendering, your provider adds the `subscribe` function to the 
 application context. This is optional, depending on if you want to hold a unique state in your app:

```
render() {
  <YourProvider>
    <App/>
  </YourProvider>
}
```

An example for a component that want's to listen to events:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.subscribe(MyEvent, this.onEvent);
}
```

In order for the component to get the `subscribe` in the `props`, the user can wrap his component with your wrapper component like this:

```
<SubscribeProvider>
  <MyComponent/>
</SubscribeProvider>
```

or use a `withSubscribe` function that you also implement.

Comment: Is this the same as higher order components? (HOC)

Comment: Yeap, I've posted an example on how to implement this HOC, also added an optional provider to the root (If needed)